# What exactly is the connection between gauge transformations and symmetry groups?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, gauge-theory, group-theory, gauge-symmetry

For a given gauge transformation, say, the electromagnetic field, where observable quantities aren't affected by transformations of the form
$$\mathbf{A}' = \mathbf{A} + \nabla \chi,$$
$$\phi' = \phi - \frac{\partial \chi}{\partial t},$$
$$\Psi' = \Psi \cdot \exp(\frac{iq\chi}{\hbar}).$$

What exactly does the $U(1)$ symmetry Lie group have to do with these gauge transformation?

Comment: Group has nothing to do with them. They form a group! Very simple fact -- if you do one gauge transformation and from that one another one => the resulting transformation (a product) will be again a gauge transformation. So the product of two transformations is again a gauge transformation. That is it. They form a group.

Comment: @AsphirDom there is more than closure to a group

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The group $\mathrm U(1)$ can be described as the set of complex numbers of unit modulus with the group multiplication given by multiplication of complex numbers.  Given this characterization, notice that the transformation
$$
  \Psi \to e^{iq\chi/\hbar} \Psi
$$
constitutes an action of $\mathrm  U(1)$ on the Dirac field $\Psi$.  If $\chi$ is then promoted to a function of spacetime position, in other words if we consider a *local* action of $\mathrm  U(1)$ on the fields, and if we introduce the gauge field $A_\mu$ into the theory, then the theory becomes a $\mathrm  U(1)$ gauge theory in the sense that the action of the theory is invariant under the local $\mathrm  U(1)$ transformation.

Comment: So, U(1) is just the set of all possible values by which $\Psi$ is multiplied due to the gauge field $\chi$?

Comment: @abhishek Pretty much.  $\mathrm U(1)$ is the set of all values that $\Psi$ can be multiplied by when we perform a *global* transformation, namely one for which the $\chi$ doesn't depend on spacetime position.  Once we take it to depend on spacetime position, we would say that we're performing a $\mathrm U(1)$ *gauge* transformation.  In that case, it is necessary to introduce $A_\mu$ as a sort of auxiliary field in order for the action of the theory to be invariant under this gauged version of the $\mathrm U(1)$, and it is *this* new field $A_\mu$ that is typically called the gauge field.